# Cannot mock icons for react-inlinesvg Jest testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs

Getting the stacktrace

```
SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.

  at XMLHttpRequest.open (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:482:15)
  at http (node_modules/httpplease/lib/index.js:106:9)
  at Function.get (node_modules/httpplease/lib/index.js:139:16)
  at InlineSVG.getFile (node_modules/react-inlinesvg/lib/index.js:151:14)
  at InlineSVG.load (node_modules/react-inlinesvg/lib/index.js:193:19)
  at callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10764:12)
  at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10797:7)
  at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14264:11)
  at commitAllLifeCycles (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15342:7)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:100:14)
```

When rendering SVG icons. My mock is configured in package.json as `"\\.(svg|ttf|jpg)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js", and`fileMock.js`'s contents are:

```
module.exports = 'test-file-mock';
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test-file-mock` is the string not matching the desired pattern. Replace it with an empty string, ie:

```
module.exports = '';
```